# Jquery modify div created from html before appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that appends a div to another div.

Something like:

```
var div = ...some html

$("#mydiv").append(div);
```

However I want to do some stuff to the div I just added. Currently I want to hide a sub part of the new div, and add a object as data. Something like

```
 var div = ...some html   
 $("#mydiv").append(div);
 $(my new div).find(".subDiv").hide(); 
 $(my new div).data('user',object);
```

But how should I get the the new div I created? Is there a way to create it and then preform these actions, and then append it? Or should I append it and then retrieve it and modify it?

Efficiency is important as this will be iterated for search results...

Thanks!

I used this as my solution thanks to Tricker:

```
var div = ...a lagre piece of html;
var newDiv = $(div);
newDiv.find("[show='contractor']").hide();
newDiv.data('user', userObject);
$(appendDiv).append(newDiv);
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can chain function calls in jQuery, and you really should read the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) as the `appendTo` function would have suited your needs better.

The entire thing could have been written as:
`$(div).data('user', userObject).appendTo(appendDiv).find('[show="contractor"]').hide();`

Comment: does appendTo return the parent or child object? I looked in the API and I can't find it. However, this could be written as `$(appendDiv).append($(div).data('user',userObject).find("[show-'contractor']").hide());` I think, and that would be the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way u want is like this:

```
var new_obj = $('<div class="subDiv"></div>');

$("#my_div").append(new_obj);

//You dont have to find the subdiv because the object "new_obj" is your subDiv
new_obj.hide();
new_obj.data('user',object);
```

Comment: I like this, do I have to do the .hide() and .data after the append? Or can I append after? or is it better this way?

Comment: @Tricker - good answer except that his subDiv could be _inside_ the new div so I suggest change it to: `var new_obj = $('<div class="newDiv"></div>');` then `new_obj.html('your data including the subDiv')` ...etc

Comment: sorry i didn't see your answer earlier, had to click refresh on the page... speaking of ajax... why are the new answers not loaded via ajax so I don't have to click refresh?... buy anyways that neither here nor there....

Comment: @kralco626 - hmm your comment in the other answer makes sense (you should have described that in your question) and yes, if all your subDiv will be hidden then use that in CSS instead of JS!

Comment: @ifaour - can't use css because There is subdiv1 and subdiv2 and sometimes subdiv1 will be hidden and sometimes subdiv2. This is decided by a property of the object that I am trying to store as data.

Comment: @ifaour thats true, but if im understanding his question. Then he would take care off it that is not going to happend. i was also going out of the "perfect" situation. and if he programs his programm good it wil not going to happen

Comment: How about toms solution? That should be even more efficient no?

Comment: @kralco626, in my case i create an object and only that object i hide. so all other subdiv's will not hide because i said that object new_div should hide.. When you will search(.find('.subDiv')) then all others will hide two

Comment: oooo .append returns the new object that was appended to. Not that object that was appended. That makes sence.

Comment: @kralco626, You edited your question. What you are doing know is you add a new object to the parent(in this case #myDiv) you insert by appending the object in to the parent after that you going to look for the same (just insert) subDiv. 

If you wanted more efficient, why should you search for it if you already have the object thats creating the subDiv. (If you append the object you dont lose it, its still in the variable)

Comment for in the future, how bigger you parent div is going to be how slower your function is going to get! because your have to look for it.. 

Goodluck with it

Comment: @Tricker - I don't understand what your saying. Are you saing that I should do the show=contractor part differently? Sorry you lost me.

Answer (score 3):

Does .append() not return the new item?

```
var myNewDiv= $("#mydiv").append(div);
```

Comment: hum... good point lol. That should be even better than Trickers solution... i think this is more efficient?

Comment: You could also just keep building

$("#mydiv").append(div).hide().data('user',object);

Comment: Good answer, however I need to get the object I just created, append returns the div that the new object was appened to i think, not the actual new object. $("#myDiv").append(div).hide(); is equilivent to saying: `$("#myDiv").append(div)` and then `$("#myDiv").hide()` I think... which is not what I want.

Comment: You're right.  how about using appendTo?  div.appendTo("#myDiv").hide().data('user',object);

Answer (score 0):

since it will always be the last child div, I believe you can access it via `$("#myDiv div:last-child")`

Comment: ya I thought about that, although I wasn't sure how. But i wans't sure that was efficient. I thought maybe there would be a better way, something like: `div = ...some html; o = createObject(div); o..find().hide(); o.data('user',object);$("#myDiv").append(o);`

Comment: but I don't know too much about how that creation proccess normally works to get html into an "object" in the DOM...

Comment: for efficiency, you could put the new DIV in a var:`var $newDIV = $("#myDiv div:last-child");` then perform your tasks on the var.

Comment: also this would limit me to adding divs syncronously. If I wanted to make multiple ajax calls to populate this would not work.

Comment: I think the question that really needs to be asked is - why doesn't your web service return the object in its correct form in the first place?

Comment: @ifaour - so I take it I cannot do anythign like i'm suggesting, create the object then modifying, and then adding?

Comment: @kralco626 - please have a look at Tricker's answer, his approach is even better except for the subDiv part as I think it's _inside_ the new div :)

Comment: well, the "object" or html div, is being created in javascript. idk if thats the best way to do it or not, but thats the way I know how. I return a C# object via the service call, then use the data in that object to populate parts of the div, then add the div to my result set. so I then want to associate the data object with the div. However, yes I could hide the subDiv in the html by setting display:none; however there are actually several subDivs to hide, that all have the same class... so I thought I would just hide all divs with that class...